# Error al generar y descargar reporte (JasperReports)

Tags: jasper-reports

Estoy realizando un listado para descarga de facturas, pero al momento de generar un reporte con muchos conceptos o que éste crece demasiado, me está lanzando una excepcion, la cual copio a continuación

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.suspend()V
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner.suspend(JRContinuationSubreportRunner.java:74)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.suspendSubreportRunner(JRBaseFiller.java:1829)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.addPage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1833)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1916)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1945)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:731)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:285)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:132)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:644)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
>       at org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.StackRecorder.execute(StackRecorder.java:104)
>       at org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.continueWith(Continuation.java:172)
>       at org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:129)
>       at org.apache.commons.javaflow.Continuation.startWith(Continuation.java:100)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRContinuationSubreportRunner.start(JRContinuationSubreportRunner.java:53)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.prepare(JRFillSubreport.java:725)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTableSubreport.prepareSubreport(FillTableSubreport.java:159)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.prepare(FillTable.java:307)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.prepare(JRFillComponentElement.java:129)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:393)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:352)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2023)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:755)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:265)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:836)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:765)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:84)

No se si alguien de ustedes haya pasado por un caso similar o que pueda orientarme con este caso.

Comment: usas maven o algo parecido? puedes indicar que versión tienes de jasper. **NoSuchMethodError** es comun que aparezca cuando no tenemos correctas nuestras veriones de dependencias

Comment: La version es la 4.1.3, es un jar

Comment: hay alguna razon en especial, por la que usas esa version en particular, es algo vieja. Por otro lado que versio de commons-javaflow usas?

Comment: disculpa la demora en responder, con respecto a lo que me preguntas es commons-javaflow-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1):

La primera recomendación que te haria es que actualizaras tu version de jasper a una 5.X almenos (este año ya estamos en 6.X)

Si por alguna razon necesitas forzosamente usar esa versión de jasper
**Debes de actualizas tu version de javaflow** prueba con esta [versión](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.apache.commons/commons-javaflow/1590792)

Esta si tiene  el metodo `suspend` en la clase `Continuation`

```
public static Object suspend() {
    return suspend(null);
}
```

Comment: Buen dia, descargue la version 6.3.0 en un zip pero veo que incluye jasperreports-6.3.0.jar, jasperreports-fonts-6.3.0.jar, y jasperreports-javaflow-6.3.0.jar, pero no veo la de commons javaflow, sera acaso que para esta version solo sea necesaria la de jasperreports-javaflow en vez de la commons, disculpa el tipo de pregunta, la verdad soy nuevo en esta parte de generacion de reportes, no se si puedes recomendarme alguna en especifico o si con esa estaria bien

Comment: hice una modificacio en el comentario, no se si tuviste oportunidad de leer :)

Comment: No te preocupes no pasa nada, commons javaflow es una libreria muy vieja y la nueva version de javaflows solo es para algunos casos `La versión Javaflow de JasperReports se debe utilizar en entornos en los que el desove múltiples hilos plantea un problema.

Este sería el caso con el servidor J2EE, pero sólo si desea generar informes en el interior del contenedor EJB, lo cual no tiene mucho sentido. Usted debe ser la generación de informes en el interior del contenedor Web, donde el desove hilos no suele ser problemático.`

Comment: Comenzare a realizar prueba, cualquier resultado lo estare publicando

Comment: Buen dia, el viernes ya se tuvo un proceso de prueba, pero no se llegó a nada, la version descargada fue la 6.3.0 parece que todo sigue igual, seguiré checando

Comment: @omarsinho Tienes el mismo error? podrias actualizar la pregunta, con la nueva traza de error

Comment: Basicamente es lo mismo lo que aparece

Comment: Buena tarde, esto es lo que arroja  javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446393 Maybe; nested exception is: 
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810057: Could not load class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 57 completed: Maybe

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo de tu *stack trace*, me parece un problema compatibilidad de versión de javaflow. La tuya no contiene `void Continuation.suspend()`, que es utilizado por el algoritmo single-thread de tu versión de Jasper Reports.

La versión mas nueva de javaflow contiene `Object Continuation.suspend()`. Esto se vé aqui: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/sandbox/javaflow/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/javaflow/Continuation.java?r1=733503&r2=958247

La versión mas nueva de Jasper Reports intenta utilizar a `void Continuation.suspend()`, como se vé aqui: https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/master/tree/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRContinuationSubreportRunner.java

Mi conclusión es que se necesita de una versión específica de javaflow con la "buena" definición de `Continuation.suspend()`. Yo hago import de la mía con Maven:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-javaflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-javaflow</artifactId>
            <version>20060411</version>
        </dependency>
```